# Unable to resolve service for type in ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to add migrations with `dnx ef migrations add Mig`, I have the following exception in console:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.IHttpContextAcccessor' while attempting to
>   activate 'NewLibrary.Models.ApplicationDbContext'.

My *ApplicationDbContext*:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

How should I correctly add dependencies to `ApplicationDbContext` constructor?

Comment: Why would your `DbContext` need a dependency on `IApplicationBuilder`. I'm just curious.

Comment: @Nkosi updated answer, I need `IHttpContextAccesor` because my database connection string depends on current user, but that's changes nothing, still this error.

Comment: My question still applies, now just for `IHttpContextAccessor`. You seem to be mixing concerns given the information you provided

Comment: @Nkosi I need to get current user claims from HttpContext, get library name from them,and change connection string respectively to current user library name.

Comment: Which exists during migration? Is `HttpContext` available at that point?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not sure what do you mean, but we already have HttpContext, when we implement `ApplicationDbContext` in some controller, where we need that context.

Comment: Is the migration happening at runtime or via command line?

Comment: @Nkosi via command line I can't add migration, it throws exception above.  At runtime, I tried `Database.Migrate()`, but it throws exception, that I don't have migrations before.

Comment: As expected. Migration is not done at run time, where DI would have been configured and available. DI would not have been setup via command line, which is why you are getting the above exception.

Comment: @Nkosi You have the answer. Are you going to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DI would not have been setup via command line, which is why you are getting the above exception.

In the comments you explain that you want access to the `HttpContext` via `IHttpContextAccessor` which is something that is usually available at run time.

Migrations are not applied at run time, where DI would have been configured and available.

You may need to read up on [Configuring a DbContext](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html#configuring-a-dbcontext). This documentation is for EF7 onwards

Comment: Your link [Setting up connection strings and dependency injection](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html#setup-connection-strings-and-dependency-injection) refers to Entity Framework 6. Is this applied to EF Core? What about migrations, if we register context as service, not via `AddEF()` extension in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Apologies I was researching both versions. will update with EF Core link

Comment: I have found the solution, just to put all in `OnConfiguring` into `try-catch` block, so, when you apply migrations, no exceptions will throw via command line.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this forum that led me to the following solution: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4232

Create a new service class and interface:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using MyProject.Interfaces;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace MyProject.Web.Services
    {
        public interface IUserResolverService
        {
            string GetCurrentUser();
        }

        public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService
        {
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
            public UserResolverService(IEnumerable<IHttpContextAccessor> context)
            {
                _context = context.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            public string GetCurrentUser()
            {
                return _context?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "unknown_user";
            }
        }
    }
```

And register it with your DI container (Startup.cs for example)

```
    services.AddTransient<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();
```

Then in your DbContext, use the userResolverService to get the username instead of IHTTPContextAccessor

```
    private readonly IUserResolverService userResolverService;
    public ApplicationDbContext(IUserResolverService userResolverService) : base()
    {
        this.userResolverService = userResolverService;

        var username = userResolverService.GetCurrentUser();
...
```

Comment: @YuriyN. Edited my answer to make it more clear.  Use userResolverService in your DbContext class to get the username.  Hope that helps!